# Setuptools, and proper build sequence (tests, lint, build...)

Tags: python, build, setuptools

I'm really new to setuptools, my only experience for Python was PyBuild until I needed a proper pip package for my project dependency.
I can build (`python setup.py build`), I can lint (`python setup.py flake8`), and I can test (`python setup.py test`).

Now, i'd like to be able to build my project as a simple single sequence from a single command. As PyBuild, or any maven/whatever CI script would.

I am a bit overwhelmed by the documentation, and a bit lazy. My question is pretty simple how can I achieve a proper build sequence that failed on flake8/unittest warnings ?

EDIT: To be even more clear:

What simple and usual command line instruction that I could put in my README can ensure new developers to first running Unit tests and Lint tests, and then build my project (that is not a bash script), and optionally push it to my private repository ?
Most of the projects I use in node, or php, or java, or whatever provides a command that ensure a build cycle chaining quality tools before triggering the actual build and deployment.

I'm pretty disturbed by the absence of such a feature in setuptools.

Comment: You don't generally *"build"* Python, most people either just `pip install` or run the tests using `python setup.py test` (in which it's possible to include linting if you like). A good starting point for creating a package is http://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/, but your question as it stands is a bit broad for SO.

Comment: Thanks Jon, so it is more a philosophic question as usual with python than binding setuptools with a blocking behavior if test or linting fails.
Well thanks for the document, I'll read it thoroughly as soon as I can.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask.